# Is this an effective way to prevent brute force attacks?

Tags: security, brute-force

I need your opinions on whether or not this is an effective way of preventing brute force attacks for user logins:

1. If the user incorrectly types the password to the account 5 times, they are locked out for 5 minutes.
2. Upon getting locked out, a record is added to my database that holds the user_id and the time at which the user can attempt to log back into that account.
3. After the 5 minutes is up, when they next try to login, it will check the database to see if the lockout time is up. If it is, they have another 5 attempts, if not, show an error.

Is this anti-brute-force proof?

Thanks.

Comment: You need a mechanism to allow a legitimate user who has forgotten his/her password, to 'reset' the brute force lockout period.

Comment: You can also use a captcha.

Comment: Long password phrases still seem a better idea to me because this has a potential to lock out many legit users.

Comment: Can an attacker have infinite time? If so, nothing is really brute force proof.

Comment: even without this, since it's over a network, the amount of time it takes to send one login request is quick, but still long enough to make things secure without a lockout period

Answer (score 5):

There is a very old, and so far the best, method of preventing brute force. It originated many years ago in unix and, so far, is still valid. It is also very simple to implement: add sleep(3) to every login attempt. 
Normal user won't have any issue with having to wait extra 3 seconds on the login action, and this coupled with proper firewall that limits amount of connections from single host is the most efficient brute force killer.

Answer (score 3):

I think a doubling delay time combined with a multiword password phrase (think `"stack overflow answers"`, probably add something simple yet easy to remember so we're good against dictionary attacks as well) would be almost completely brute-force-proof as well as unobtrusive towards users. Here is what I mean, let's assume the initial interval of 1 second:

- 1st fail: 1 sec delay
- 2nd fail: 2 sec delay
- 3rd fail: 4 sec delay
- 4th fail: 8 sec delay
- etc...

At this point probably every legit user would figure out he has forgotten the password and would look for a way to reset it.

[image: length]

Comment: How does this defend against brute-force attacks? How would you check whether it is the 1st, 2nd, etc... attempt to login? It is very easy to start a new session by every attempt or send multiple requests parallel...

Comment: @inf3rno Think of the resources needed to initiate each login with new session/IP for cracking a long password... it's as expensive as a huge DDOS attack. There's no finite defense against a brute-force attack, all you can do is buy more time and make them give up.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

**Locking Account**

You lock the accounts for some time, after some number of incorrect login attempts.

Problems:

- Ineffective against slow attacks that try only a few logins on relative large intervals of time.
- The attacker can lock a lot of accounts, consider this a DoS.
- The attacker can get some info of your site, dependeing on the error responses.

**Locking IP**

You lock the IP with varius failed logins.

Problems:

- This can lock large groups of users
- Ineffective against automated tools that use proxys.

**Do pauses**

You do pauses when checking the password, this will slow the attack.

Problems:

- The attack can be multi-threaded, so you are more or less in the same situation.

**Captcha**

There are good algorithms that can correctly identify that weird shapes/letters/numers.

The captcha is not 100% effective, but could slow down the attack.

**Login for certain IPs**

Give the users the option to allow login only from certain IP's.

- This is not practical for every user.

**Add no predictable behavior**

For example, use different error messages each time when a login fails, this could mislead automated tools.

Comment: Captcha was NEVER 100% effective. I can't recall time in it's, damned, life when it was even 50% effective, not to mention 100%. What it always was, and is, is severe annoyance to legitimate users and general pain in the behind.

Comment: So what do you think is the best solution?

Comment: @inf3rno Hello. I think it highly depends on the situation, not every brute force attacks are same, some are more sofisticated than others. In general a combination of _Account Lockout_ with _Throttle Requests_ is enough for common web sites. Also, users should be using complex passwords (this can be forced in the sign up form). And always try to reveal the minimum critical information in error messages as possible.

Comment: Do you think it is necessary to allow recover by lockout? How would you solve that, e.g. with activation email?

Comment: @inf3rno Well, that's a good point. There could be some mechanism to allow the accounts to reopen for legitimate users, if it is really neccesary or not i dont know, that depends. There are several ways (some more "weak" than the other): time-based unlock, self unlock (as you mentioned: email (or maybe cell-phone sms)), manual unlock (job for the admin).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the correct track.  You should increment a counter field for the user in the database for each consecutive invalid password attempt.  If you are trying to hold that value in a session or cookie, a malicious user could keep destroying that and retrying after 4 attempts.

I employ a similar strategy -- after 5 wrong attempts, we require captcha.  After 10 wrong attempts, we block the account until reset.  We have a reset password and unlock strategy in place, as well.

Someone had mentioned a sleep(3) strategy.  While, it's a good idea to not return responses for user authentication too quickly, it's probably not tamper-proof.  An attacker could spawn a series of concurrent authentication requests, instead of a quick series of consecutive requests.  At least, with your strategy, you know they are only getting 2400 guesses per day, per user.  Consider cutting off the user for longer periods than 5 minutes, especially once they pass 10 or 15 guesses.

For the paranoid, log additional data with each of the bad attempts, such as IP address, user agent string, and other http headers in the request.  You may be able to identify patterns in the event of a real attack.

Consider including logging and alerting appropriate personnel for when a user is locked out.

Comment: And as a comment on the content, with lock-out you are open for all sorts of griefing, where a malicious person can just lock desired person account over and over and over, making it impossible for him to actually use the system. And no, limiting it by IP won't help since headers can be spoofed, and a griefer doesn't care that he won't receive the response - login action will be performed and this is what counts.

Comment: As a comment on the second comment, lockout is considered a valid security strategy, and is required by many security frameworks, like PCI Compliance requirement 8.5.13.  There are pros and cons to any method, right?  I would rather be in the position of having a malicious person only being able to lockout a valid person, rather than being able to impersonate the person and access the service.  For example, I would rather be locked out of my online banking account, than have access along with an imposter also having access.

Comment: Which is a standard scenario, when every now and then you will run into a lockout on your account. But doesn't in any way respond to the scenario that i've proposed - where a culprit is causing a constant lock-out on almost all of your user accounts (which are very easy to gather of the internet). What are you going to do then? What will be the change you will make in the system to counter that?

Comment: Two-factor authentication.

Comment: What about it? You will suddenly assign all of the people a 2-way auth when this sort of attack will take place? Or do you mean that you will not lock someone out if he will make wrong-password requests without the valid auth token? If its the latter, you are just making the bruteforce more complex as there are two passwords to guess (assuming that the 2-way is implemented right, which very often is done in a very wrong way), and you in no way provide the desired lock-out against brute force, especially since it will be a "hit" so rarely that it will fly over the filter.

Comment: It seems that if you have an initial challenge/response, as some may have automated with some CSRF hidden field, it would be more difficult for a griefer.  I don't think they could spoof the ip address and still receive the http response, without revealing their identity or the identity of some proxy they control?

Comment: Are you going to tie CSRF token to the specific IP address of a person that requested it? If not - scrape it from actual IP, then send requests from fake ones. If you do - be ready to have your database flooded until it flips (because you have to carry unlimited amount of tokens for every given IP at any given time, never know how many people share one). The correct answer is to move the lock-out moment. When account is being attacked, you mark it like so but don't lock it. You lock it at next successful login and then require off-site verification for this account before it is unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

the problem can be solved in windows server

1- install [vnc server](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/) on your server

2- test your vnc server with [vnc viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/) and make sure you can connect to server

3- disable nlmp

for disable nlmp follow this instruction :

- open start menu , type "local security policy" and open this app
- from the left panel , find "local policies" and open it
- under the local policies find "security Options" and open it
- in the right panel , find "Network security: Restrict NTLM: Incoming NTLM traffic" and open it
- there's just one combo box in there , in default that combo is blank , change the option to "deny all account" then click ok .

done !
you disabled hole nlmp system and no one can access to this protocol
and brute force attack will be done .

(Alert) be careful , after disable nlmp from your server , Remote Desktop will be disable and no one can connect to it , Even you !

now you can use vnc view to connect to your server .

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will restrict bruteforce . but some recovery procedure should be there for the legitimate users.